The company continues growing on sales. or The company continues growing sales




The company continues growing on sales.





The company continues growing sales.

It seems to me these two sentencens are of the same meaning.
If that is the case
Is the word "on" in the first sentence an adverb?
If that is NOT the case
Is the word "on" in the first sentence a preposition?

They mean different things: the second means they are increasing the volume of sales; the first is less clear what you mean, but probably means the company is increasing in size due to its sales. Grow can be transitive (making something else grow) or intransitive (growing oneself).

The company's sales continue to grow or increase. You shouldn't separate sales and company. It makes little sense. Ideas don't grow on trees.

To mean that sales (revenue) continues to increase, the usual phrasing is more like #2, "The company continues growing sales."
The word order can be changed, with the same meaning: "The company's sales continue growing" or "The company continues growing revenue."
The first sentence does seem to say something slightly different -- that the company is growing on the basis of sales. This phrasing is unusual because sales (revenue) is the most common measure of company growth. However, I guess this phrasing might be used in making a comparison. For example: "Company A continues growing on investor funding, while company B continues growing on sales."
